# Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[PublicKeyService]

Tags: angular

```
app.public-key-service.ts


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import { WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';

@Injectable()
export class PublicKeyService {
  private tenantId = '';
  private jwks_uri = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}/discovery/v2.0/keys`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private getBaseUrl(): string {
    let baseUrl = 'https://' + window.location.hostname;

    if (window.location.port && window.location.port !== '443') {
      baseUrl = baseUrl + ':' + window.location.port;
    }

    return baseUrl;
  }

  private getPublicKeys(): any {
    return this.http.get<{ keys }>(this.jwks_uri);
  }

  public getClientSettings() {

    const metadata = {
      issuer: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}/v2.0`,
      authorization_endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
      token_endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
    };

    const add_signing_keys = function (keys_array) {
      return {
        metadata: metadata,
        singingKeys: keys_array,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
        client_id: `${environment.secureAuthClientId}`,
        redirect_uri: `${this.getBaseUrl()}/auth-callback`,
        post_logout_redirect_uri: this.getBaseUrl(),
        response_type: 'id_token',
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        filterProtocolClaims: true,
        loadUserInfo: false,
        automaticSilentRenew: false,
        checkSessionInterval: 1000000,
        userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: sessionStorage })
      };
    };

    return this.http.get<{ keys }>(this.jwks_uri).pipe(
      map(val => add_signing_keys(val.keys))
    );
  }
}
```

authentication-secure-auth-service.ts

```
    import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User, WebStorageStateStore} from 'oidc-client';

import {PublicKeyService} from '../../security/services/app.public-key-service';
import {UserService} from '../../shared/services/user.service';
import {KnownAuthenticationTypes} from '../types/known-authentication-types';
import {Login} from '../types/login';
import {LoginDto} from '../types/login-dto';
import {LoginMap} from '../types/login-map';
import {ChangePassword} from '../../settings/types/change-password';
import {ChangePasswordDto} from '../../settings/types/change-password-dto';
import {ChangePasswordMap} from '../../settings/types/change-password-map';
import {ResetPasswordRequestDto} from '../types/reset-password-request-dto';
import {BaseDto} from '../../shared/types/base-dto';
import * as Oidc from 'oidc-client';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {KnownRoutePath, KnownEvent} from '../../shared/types/known-routes';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationSecureAuthService implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly loginReturnUrlKey: string = 'loginReturnUrlKey';
  private user: User = null;
  private manager: UserManager;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService, private router: Router,private publicKeyService:PublicKeyService) {
    Oidc.Log.logger = console;
    Oidc.Log.level = Oidc.Log.INFO;
    this.publicKeyService.getClientSettings().subscribe(
      data =>{   
        console.log(data),
         this.manager = new UserManager(data);
         this.start(); 
    }
  );

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stop();
  }

  // Make a call to "login" to web API using id_token from SecureAuth
  loginWithIdToken(idToken: string): Observable<Login> {
    const url = `${environment.apiSecurityOrigin}/security/tokenlogin`;
    const body = {idToken: idToken};

    console.log('About to call web API to fetch user auth token and roles');
    return this.http.post<BaseDto<LoginDto>>(url, body)
      .map(baseDto => {
        console.log('Returned from calling web API to fetch user auth token and roles');
        const vm = LoginMap.toVm(this.extractLoginDto(baseDto.value));
        if (vm.authenticationType === KnownAuthenticationTypes.Authenticated) {
          this.userService.setCurrentUser(vm.authenticationToken, vm.user);
        } else {
          this.userService.clearCurrentUserAndToken();
        }
        return vm;
      })
      .catch(this.handleLoginError);
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
  }

  getIdToken(): string {
    return this.user.id_token;
  }

  getLoginReturnUrl(): string {
    let returnUrl: string = sessionStorage.getItem(this.loginReturnUrlKey);
    if (!returnUrl) {
      // Default to workqueues if sessionStorage not set.
      returnUrl = '/workqueues';
    }

    return returnUrl;
  }

  setLoginReturnUrl(returnUrl: string): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.loginReturnUrlKey, returnUrl);
  }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    }, reason => console.log('Error in signinRedirectCallback(): ' + reason));
  }

  private extractLoginDto(body: any) {
    return new LoginDto(body.authenticationToken, body.authentication, body.user);
  }

  private handleLoginError(response: Response | any) {
    return Observable.throw(response);
  }

  private start(): void {
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
  }

  private storageEventListener(event) {
    if (event.key === KnownEvent.LogoutEventName) {
      // The user logged out of another tab, so log out here.
      console.log('User logged out of another tab, so logging out now.');
      this.router.navigate([KnownRoutePath.Logout]);
    }
  }

  private stop(): void {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
  }

}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanLoad, Route} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {UserService} from '../../shared/services/user.service';
import {AlertService} from '../../shared/services/alert.service';
import {AuthenticationSecureAuthService} from '../../security/services/authentication-secure-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private authService: AuthenticationSecureAuthService
    ) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
  }

  canLoad(route: Route): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(route.path);
    return this.checkLoggedIn(route.path);
  }

  private checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
    const loggedIn = this.userService.isLoggedIn();
    const sessionCurrent = this.userService.isSessionCurrent();
    if (loggedIn && sessionCurrent) {
      return true;
    }

    if (loggedIn && !sessionCurrent) {
      this.userService.clearCurrentUserAndToken();
      this.alertService.error('Your session has expired.', true);
    }

    if (url && url.charAt(0) !== '/') {
      url = '/' + url;
    }
    this.authService.setLoginReturnUrl(url);

    this.authService.startAuthentication();
    return false;
  }
}
```

In the auth.guard.ts file we are calling start authentication.
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signinRedirect')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signinRedirect')
at AuthenticationSecureAuthService.startAuthentication (authentication-secure-auth.service.ts:116:25)
at AuthGuard.checkLoggedIn (auth.guard.ts:46:22)
at AuthGuard.canLoad (auth.guard.ts:26:17)
at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2203:1)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79:1)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92:1)
at ArrayObservable._subscribe (ArrayObservable.js:116:1)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172:1)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160:1)
at MapOperator.call (map.js:57:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:809:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:775:1)
at eval (zone.js:858:1)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744:1)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420:1)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188:1)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595:1)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500:1)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1517:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add PublicKeyService to providers of app module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  providers:    [ PublicKeyService ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

you inject the publicKeyService in "authentication-secure-auth-service" ,so you should
move the getClientSettings() function to your "authentication-secure-auth-service" class body as a public method instead of  "export function" that your declared out of setvice class body!

you can change your method like this and subscribe its result where is need:

```
public getClientSettings() {
 return  this.publicKeyService.getClientSettings(); 
}
```

but actually seems you don`t need this change.
according to your comment ,try this changes in your AuthenticationSecureAuthService constructor :

replace this part of code :

```
 this.manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());  
 this.start();
```

with this:

```
  this.publicKeyService.getClientSettings().subscribe(
      data =>{   
         this.manager = new UserManager(data);
         this.start();
    }
  );
```

Comment: I added this in my AppModule but now it is throwing different error.        ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicKeyService')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicKeyService')
    at getClientSettings (authentication-secure-auth.service.ts:133:15)
    at new AuthenticationSecureAuthService (authentication-secure-auth.service.ts:34:36)

Comment: It seems  you call a function out of your service body  and "this" object  is undefined ,you need change it , I edit answer  ,check it @sreddy

Comment: I update my code based on your suggestions and the getclientsettings expected return type is UserManagersettings. Please check my orginal post for the updated code. Now it's throwing me an error as Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No authority or metadataUrl configured on settings

Comment: in out of subscription block your method will return null as "this.keys" ,in constructor of AuthenticationSecureAuthService  you call this method to pass its return value to UserManager calss, you need some change there !

Comment: check answer`s update

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the issues. Everything is working as expected but where ever I am referencing this.manager it is throwing undefined error.  for example in the below two methods I am calling and it throws undefined error  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {    return this.manager.signinRedirect() ;}
completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {this.user = user;
    }, reason => console.log('Error in signinRedirectCallback(): ' + reason));
  }    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signinRedirect')

Comment: Update the code in the orginal post as per your suggestion

Comment: I guess the reason for this is ignoring of  async behaviour ,please show the part of code you call these methods

Comment: I added the code in the original post under auth.guard.ts.

Comment: console.log(data),
 this.manager = new UserManager(data);
check the console for data log ? do you see log of data before you got error ?
i want to know the constructor of authService has called  ?